# Camel Enrichment error: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint

Tags: routes, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to put my message through a method between two queues. This is my route:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
        <to uri="direct:adder"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:adder"/>
        <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
        <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Here is the class that has adder:

```
package com.example.integration;

public class Modifier {
    public String adder(String words) {
         System.out.println("adder entered");
         return words + 'a';
    }
}
```

The "adder entered print statement isn't ever being printed and the message doesn't have an extra "a" on the end. Any ideas why the function isn't being used?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that error message means you haven't defined a route to consume from `direct:adder`...because direct is synchronous, it requires a route/consumer be available at the time it's invoked...

see http://camel.apache.org/bean.html, it should look something like this...

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
        <to uri="direct:adder"/>
    </route>
    <route>
      <from uri="direct:adder"/>
      <to uri="myBean"/>
      <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
      <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.integration.Modifier"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! I edited my route and my code but I am having a problem where it isn't entering the direct method. I've edited my post to reflect the code changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: you just need to reference your Modifier bean in the direct route...updated my example as well

Comment: Thank you so much, the direct reference fixed my problems!